# Flex 4 UIComponent width and height remains zero after addChild is called

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, uicomponents, addchild

I have a component `ObjectHolder` which extends `UIComponent` that holds many children `UIComponents`. However, after using `addChild()` to add these children to `ObjectHolder`, its width and height remain zero.  Is it possible for the `UIComponent` to automatically expand to the size of its containing children components?

```
public class ObjectHolder extends UIComponent
{       
    public function ObjectHolder()
    {
        var c1:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
        c1.graphics.beginFill( 0xffffff );
        c1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        addChild( c1 );
        trace( this.width );  // Displays zero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the component's size you should [implement `measure()` method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_advanced_3.html#203719). But you should also follow other [recommendations on creating custom components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html). In your case you should create and add child component in [`createChildren()` method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_advanced_3.html#203624).

Comment: A component never sizes itself.  Implementing the measure() method only provides a "Suggestion" to that components parent container via measuredHeight and measuredWidth properties.  Most default Flex containers will honor those sizes, though.

Comment: @PeterBZ In this case after adding a child you should call `invalidateSize()` which call measure in the next frame.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Of course you're right. But in case if there is no explicit size for the component all the layout containers or layouts rely on measurements performed by `measure()`. I suppose as far as author asked this question he wasn't set explicit sizes.

Comment: @PeterBZ While laying out components within layout containers (in your case component is `ObjectHolder` and container is `Grid` I suppose) you have several possibilities for sizing. You can set explicit width or height in pixels (I mean setting it outside your `ObjectHolder`). You can set it in percents (`percentWidth` or `percentHeight`). You can set min and max sizes. All these values are taking in mind why laying out. And `measure()` is a way tell to the container which sizes component wants to be (desired sizes).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the UIComponent to automatically expand to the size
>   of its containing children components?

The formal answer is no.  A component is never responsible for setting it's own height and width values; it is only responsible for sizing and positioning it's children based on the values set by that component's parent.

If you implement a measure() method in your component, you can use it to set the measuredWidth and measuredHeight of your component.  This will, in essence, be a suggestion that you provide to your parent's container on what is the ideal size you need to position and size all your child elements properly.  Your own components should be sized and positioned in updateDisplayList() based on the unscaledWidth and unscaledHeight values passed in.

Most of the time the Flex default containers will honor these sizing values; although there are situations where they will not be.  For example, if the size the child container needs is more than the size of the parent.